# gstreamer: delay stream relative to others

Tags: synchronization, delay, gstreamer

I'm having a gstreamer pipeline with various streams, and I need to delay one of them so they are synched.

The streams are captured live and there is some pre-processing before the actual capture, that adds different delays to the streams, so they reach the computer out of sync and gstreamer's internal synching doesn't help; I'm trying to re-synchronise them.

I tried using the trick with `queue`'s `min-threshold-time` property mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977233/pipeline-gstremer-video-streaming-with-delay), but this does not help, as the pipeline will still sync all buffers based on their timestamps - so the entire pipeline gets delayed, not just a single stream.

My current pipeline looks like:

```
+-----------+
|decklinksrc|
+-----------+
     |
     V
  +------+
  |tee   |
  +------+
     |  |                     +-------------+
     |  +-------------------> | xvimagesink |
     V                        +-------------+
  +-----+
  |queue|
  +-----+
     |
     V                    +------------+
  +-------+               |jackaudiosrc|
  |x264env|               +------------+
  +-------+                     |
     |                          V
     V                       +-----+
  +---------+                |faac |
  |h264parse|                +-----+
  +---------+                   |
     |                          V
     V                      +--------+
  +-----+                   |aacparse|
  |queue|                   +--------+
  +-----+                       |
     |    +---------------------+
     V    V
  +----------+
  |flvmux    |
  +----------+
     |
     V
  +-----+
  |queue|
  +-----+
     |
     V
  +---------+
  |rtmpsink |
  +---------+
```

As I'm currently only trying to delay a video stream, I also tried using the `frei0r-filter-delay0r` element (which wraps the *frei0r* video-delay plugin), but this only works with `RGBA`-video (mine is `YUY2`) and conversion is too costy.

I *think* that I need an element that adds (or subtracts) an offset to the timestamp of any buffer it receives, but haven't found such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Some sink elements have a render-delay property.  Could you use that?

Edit: You could also try an identity element with the sleep-time property:

```
identity sleep-time=25000
```

Edit2: Also make sure you have a "queue" element for both pipelines attached to the "tee" element.

```
tee name=t ! queue ! x264 ! ...
t. ! queue ! xvimagesink
```

It's hard to know what could be the cause of the stuttering without seeing it or having more logging details.

Comment: i don't think so. the streams (one of which i need to delay) are muxed before sent to a sink.

Comment: So what is the gist of your pipeline?  How many inputs, how many outputs?  Can you trace it out?

Comment: addea screenshot of my pipeline to the question. i want to delay what's coming out of the `decklinksrc`

Comment: So you want both the xvimagesink and rtmpsink to be delayed by the same amount?  Are you running this from the command line or an application?

Comment: `xvimagesink` is only for monitoring/checking the signal (i dont particularily care about delaying it). The pipeline is run from a qt application written in python.

Comment: Did you try adding an identity element with the sleep-time property?

Comment: i'm still not sure. it seems that the video becomes quite jerky when i delay the video for e.g. *360 ms* (that's *360000 us*)