# GStreamer RTP packet size

Tags: rtp, gstreamer

I'm running the following GStreamer command:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=audiofile.mp3 ! mad ! audioconvert ! rtpL16pay mtu=1024 ! udpsink port=5005 host=127.0.0.1`

This sets up a RTP stream with a maximum packet size of 1024 bytes (Maximum Transmission Unit). When I run this stream, I end up getting a sequence of 4 packets of size 1024 followed by 1 packet of size 572. This sequence is repeated for the duration of the file. Why is this happening, and is there any way to ensure a uniform packet size (at least until the last packet)?

Comment: Hi, just wondering if you ever found a way to control the packet size

Answer (score 3):

The RTP packet size is the minimum of either the MTU, max-ptime (if set) or available data.

So in your case, without more information, I suspect the packet size of 572 bytes is because it's all the available or remaining data in the pipeline at that point.

If you want to ensure 1024 bytes are always available, look into implementing a [queue](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-queue.html) to buffer data for your rtpL16pay element.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying to insert `queue min-threshold-bytes=1024` after `audioconvert` and it doesn't seem to be making a difference. Would you be able to provide an example of queue usage in gstreamer? I can't seem to find any.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977233/pipeline-gstremer-video-streaming-with-delay) can help as a generic example. You can debug your `gst-launch` generated pipeline with `GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR`.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, none of my attempts at using `queue` have resulted in any change to the packet sizing whatsoever. Perhaps I shall have to look elsewhere.

Comment: I think you'd want the `queue min-threshold-bytes=1024` to be just before the final udpsink.   `gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=audiofile.mp3 ! mad ! audioconvert ! rtpL16pay mtu=1024 ! queue min-threshold-bytes=1024 ! udpsink port=5005 host=127.0.0.1`

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that as well- no luck. I honestly haven't gotten any discernible effects whatsoever from any of my various attempts at using `queue`, so I'm still rather confused by whether I'm doing something syntactically wrong. But no error messages either, sooo....