# GStreamer UDPSink blocksize property not working?

Tags: udp, gstreamer

I'm using GStreamer and sending audio using this pipeline:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=soundfile.mp3 ! mad ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw, layout=interleaved, format=F32LE, channels=2 ! udpsink blocksize=512 port=5005 host=127.0.0.1`

However, `blocksize` doesn't appear to be working at all. This is the doc for udpsink, accessed by `gst-inspect udpsink`:

```
Element Properties:
  name                : The name of the object
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: "udpsink0"
  preroll-queue-len   : Number of buffers to queue during preroll
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Unsigned Integer. Range: 0 - 4294967295 Default: 0 
  sync                : Sync on the clock
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: true
  max-lateness        : Maximum number of nanoseconds that a buffer can be late before it is dropped (-1 unlimited)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer64. Range: -1 - 9223372036854775807 Default: -1 
  qos                 : Generate Quality-of-Service events upstream
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: false
  async               : Go asynchronously to PAUSED
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: true
  ts-offset           : Timestamp offset in nanoseconds
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer64. Range: -9223372036854775808 - 9223372036854775807 Default: 0 
  enable-last-buffer  : Enable the last-buffer property
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: true
  last-buffer         : The last buffer received in the sink
                        flags: readable
                        MiniObject of type "GstBuffer"
  blocksize           : Size in bytes to pull per buffer (0 = default)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Unsigned Integer. Range: 0 - 4294967295 Default: 4096 
  render-delay        : Additional render delay of the sink in nanoseconds
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Unsigned Integer64. Range: 0 - 18446744073709551615 Default: 0 
  throttle-time       : The time to keep between rendered buffers (unused)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Unsigned Integer64. Range: 0 - 18446744073709551615 Default: 0 
  bytes-to-serve      : Number of bytes received to serve to clients
                        flags: readable
                        Unsigned Integer64. Range: 0 - 18446744073709551615 Default: 0 
  bytes-served        : Total number of bytes sent to all clients
                        flags: readable
                        Unsigned Integer64. Range: 0 - 18446744073709551615 Default: 0 
  sockfd              : Socket to use for UDP sending. (-1 == allocate)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer. Range: -1 - 2147483647 Default: -1 
  closefd             : Close sockfd if passed as property on state change
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: true
  sock                : Socket currently in use for UDP sending. (-1 == no socket)
                        flags: readable
                        Integer. Range: -1 - 2147483647 Default: -1 
  clients             : A comma separated list of host:port pairs with destinations
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: "localhost:4951"
  auto-multicast      : Automatically join/leave the multicast groups, FALSE means user has to do it himself
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: true
  ttl                 : Used for setting the unicast TTL parameter
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer. Range: 0 - 255 Default: 64 
  ttl-mc              : Used for setting the multicast TTL parameter
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer. Range: 0 - 255 Default: 1 
  loop                : Used for setting the multicast loop parameter. TRUE = enable, FALSE = disable
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: true
  qos-dscp            : Quality of Service, differentiated services code point (-1 default)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer. Range: -1 - 63 Default: -1 
  send-duplicates     : When a distination/port pair is added multiple times, send packets multiple times as well
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: true
  buffer-size         : Size of the kernel send buffer in bytes, 0=default
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer. Range: 0 - 2147483647 Default: 0 
  host                : The host/IP/Multicast group to send the packets to
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: "localhost"
  port                : The port to send the packets to
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer. Range: 0 - 65535 Default: 4951
```

This is already somewhat confusing, as the default value for `blocksize` is listed as both 0 and 4096. It seems that it is 4096, however, as that is my UDP packet size no matter what value I use for `blocksize`. What's more confusing is that I can scarcely find any mention of the `blocksize` property anywhere online, even in GStreamer's own documentation: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-udpsink.html

The only properties mentioned are `host` and `port`. Has `blocksize` been deprecated or something? And if so, is there any way to control the amount of data sent in each UDP packet? I've tried using the mtu property in RTP with no luck (see here: [gstreamer RTP packet size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30982735/gstreamer-rtp-packet-size)) and am kind of at my wits' end with this.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using gstinspect on an element, it shows you all properties - not only from a particular element but also from its parents. Which is truly expected behaviour.

`UdpSink` indeed has only `host` and `port` property. Parent - `GstMultiUDPSink` has more.

You can find an inheritance chain in GStreamer documentation in form of a tree (Object Hierarchy paragraph). Unfortunately, not all links are working correctly, so it is better to google proper link for the parent element.

Ok, back to question, `blocksize` you are mentioning is property of [`GstBaseSink`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-libs/html/GstBaseSink.html)
 and is described as:

> The amount of bytes to pull when operating in pull mode.
>   Flags: Read / Write
>
> Default value: 4096

So it defines how much data it will pull from upstream element. It will not affect UDP packets. Probably what you are looking for is `buffer-size` property of [`GstMultiUDPSink`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-multiudpsink.html#GstMultiUDPSink--buffer-size):

> “buffer-size”              gint 
>   Size of the kernel send buffer in bytes, 0=default.
>
> Flags: Read / Write
>
> Allowed values: >= 0
>
> Default value: 0