# Delaying a single branch of a tee by n seconds in a GStreamer pipeline

Tags: rust, gstreamer

Assume a pipeline like the following:

```
videotestsrc +-> timeoverlay +-> tee +-> queue +-> autovideosink
                                     |
                                     +-> queue +-> autovideosink
```

The first branch of the `tee` must act as a passthrough, simply letting samples flow onto the rest of the pipeline. The second branch must be very similar, the only difference is that it should have a delay of n seconds relative to the first branch.

Unfortunately I have not been able to achieve this by myself.

I've tried setting the `max-size-*` and `min-threshold-time` properties of the `queue` (like suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977233/pipeline-gstremer-video-streaming-with-delay) answer) of the second branch but it did not work.

I also tried to modify the running time of the second branch through `queue.get_sink_pads().first().unwrap().set_offset(-5000000000)` but alas, it also didn't work.

I also tried to attach a pad probe and retimestamp the buffers passing through the sink pad of the `queue` of the second branch to be n seconds in the future hoping that they would get retained on the `queue` until the running time of the pipeline caught up but it also didn't work (I imagine that it didn't work because even though the `tee` element creates separate branches, the buffers are still shared through a reference).

I've attached below a code snippet showing the progress I've made (which isn't much, to be honest).

Is it possible to achieve this behaviour without having to implement a plugin from scratch?

---

To try and implement this behaviour, I've begun by instantiating the basic elements ...

```rust
let videotestsrc = ElementFactory::make("videotestsrc", None)?;
let timeoverlay = ElementFactory::make("timeoverlay", None)?;
let tee = ElementFactory::make("tee", None)?;
```

... then I instantiated the pipeline ...

```rust
let pipeline = Pipeline::new(None);
pipeline.add(&videotestsrc)?;
pipeline.add(&timeoverlay)?;
pipeline.add(&tee)?;
```

... then I created the branches ...

```rust
{
    let queue = ElementFactory::make("queue", None)?;
    let autovideosink = ElementFactory::make("autovideosink", None)?;

    pipeline.add(&queue)?;
    pipeline.add(&autovideosink)?;

    tee.link(&queue)?;
    queue.link(&autovideosink)?;
}

{
    let queue = ElementFactory::make("queue", None)?;
    let autovideosink = ElementFactory::make("autovideosink", None)?;

    // queue.set_property_from_str("leaky", "downstream");
    // queue.set_property("max-size-buffers", &0u32)?;
    // queue.set_property("max-size-bytes", &0u32)?;
    // queue.set_property("max-size-time", &0u64)?;
    // queue.set_property("min-threshold-time", &5000000000u64)?;

    pipeline.add(&queue)?;
    pipeline.add(&autovideosink)?;

    tee.link(&queue)?;
    queue.link(&autovideosink)?;
}
```

The comments on the second branch are from an attempt I've made without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also tried to modify the running time of the second branch through queue.get_sink_pads().first().unwrap().set_offset(-5000000000) but alas, it also didn't work.

That's almost the solution: set a positive value and it should work. You're currently shifting it into the past. And in addition make sure to a) set the offset on the source pad of the queue, and b) that the queue can hold at least as much data as the offset you're setting.

Comment: I just tested this and it worked flawlessly. I am beginning to lose count of how many times you've saved me so far. Thank you very, very much.